Using OAuth 2 to provide Authorization for my Web API application
If I have a web API application, can I use OAuth 2.0 to control what level of access I give to user to my application?
For example, using Facebook as the Authenticator and I want to control who can delete or update records in my web API project.

No, not really. The different permissions you can ask for, are for what your app can do in the name of the user "on" Facebook. So unless you wanted to make "who can delete or update records" dependent on certain characteristics / properties of their FB account, this doesn't make much sense.

I see. Thank you. So OAuth is used for authentication and not for authorisation purpose?

No, I don't think it should be phrased like that. Of course an OAuth provider can provide different levels of permissions for use by 3rd-party applications; but Facebook's implementation is geared towards usage with their APIs, and not to provide anything outside the scope of those.

Hi C3roe, If I use Azure as the Authenticator, how would I provide different levels of permission?

I don't know if they offer anything for that. Most likely, you will still need to handle that part on your end. I mean, you need to decide who you want to grant access to what anyway, right? Thats not a decision Azure can make for you.
